# Can you limit users visibility of salesforce content separately on mobile?

Tags: salesforce1-app, security, mobile

Like what if we just want our users to be able to access the calendar from the salesforce app. When they are in using their computer we want them to have full acess, but then when they are out and about with their phones, can we limit them to only viewing their clendar or certain records/objects.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you want this on a per user basis (like managers can see contacts but employees can only see calendars) or just All users on the app can only view calendar? If it's the latter, removing the items from the navigation should be sufficient: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizing_navigation_pane.htm&type=5

Comment: Good call! Pretty sure we would rather the former, but the later definitely is a stepping stone at least to get something going and people familiar with the app.

Comment: But yes, long term (once people are a little more familiar with lighting and the app) we would like to leverage it a lot more and give unique permissions to people that are different from their desktop permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot you can do with [Session-Based Permission Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=perm_sets_session_use.htm&type=5). Basically, you can create a [login flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_login_flow.htm&type=5) that assigns permissions to a specific session. Basically, your basic profile would include only permissions they normally have, then you'd add extra permissions (via the Session-Based Permission Set) to allow them to do other stuff. In your case, it sounds like you'd restrict their basic profile for mobile, then on a web login, you'd add in extra permissions for editing the calendar, etc. I don't believe it's possible to have record-level granularity here, though, but it should get you most of the way. You can read more about this in the [Salesforce Security Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_login_flow_examples.htm). You might also want to look at [this trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/session_based_perms/units/session_based_overview).

Comment: Great info, your first link has a disclaimer at the top stating that it's for lightning only, are session based perms supported in classic?

Comment: @gNerb It's a Trailhead Module. The module itself is intended for a Lightning audience, but the feature itself works on all forms of devices, including Outlook, Salesforce1, Classic, and Lightning.

Comment: @gNerb I've changed the links up a bit. Does this help clarify?

Comment: There's just so much cool stuff in those links, still reading through them. I've done trailhead 3 times all the way through but it's been a while. I'm thinking Ill have to run through everything again.